# sudo must be setuid root error

Tags: linux, sudo

I am getting the following error while switching to root user

```
[~]# sudo su -
sudo: must be setuid root
```

The current permission of sudo is

```
[~]# ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x 2 root root 190904 Mar 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

It's may CLOUDLINUX 5.11 x86_64  cPanel live server. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you in the wheel group?

Comment: Yes, already in sudoers file with the following entry


administrator        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: But you also have to be in the wheel group. What's the output of `groups | grep wheel`?

Comment: I have fixed it my self. Currently the user is set to jailed shell and now I  changed it to normal shell and could switch to root.

@ Ortomala Lokni  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Enter system with recovery mode.(maybe Esc or Shift when start.)
Then choose the content row with 'root' in recovery menu.
Then:

```
#mount -o remount,rw /
#chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
#chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

now, restart...
try:

```
sudo ls
```

but if following exception raise:

```
#sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
#sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Then you need entering recovery mode again and try:

```
#chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

restart...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it my self. Currently the user is set to jailed shell and now I changed it to normal shell and could switch to root. – Techiescorner